# How to create same tree except leaves?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I am making a parser for BGP Communities. I decided to make it with Antlr but I am totally new. This is my input:

NO_EXPORT do not to NTT

NO_EXPORT set to CNN

NO_EXPORT prepend except CNN

NO_EXPORT do not to CNN

LOCAL_PREFERENCE do not to NTT

LOCAL_PREFERENCE do not to CNN

That is my code:

```
expression
   :   action*
   ;
action   
   :   no_export+
   |   local_preference+
   |   as_padding+
   ;
no_export
   :   'NO_EXPORT' sentencenevdn+
   |   'NO_EXPORT' sentencenevs+
   |   'NO_EXPORT' sentencenevp+
   ;
local_preference
   :   ('LOCAL_PREFERENCE' sentencelp)+
   ;
as_padding
   :   ('AS_PADDING' sentenceap)+
   ;


sentencenevdn
   :   'do not' prepdest+
   ;
sentencenevs
   :   ('set' prepdest)+
   ;
sentencenevp
   :   ('prepend' prepdest)+
   ;
sentencelp
   :   (verbs prepdest)+
   ;
sentenceap
   :   (verbs prepdest)+ 
   ;

verbs
   : ('do not'|'set'|'prepend')+
   ;

prepdest
   : 'to' dest+
   | 'except' dest+
   ;

dest
   :  DESTINATION
   ;
```

This is output:
[image: a busy cat]

As you can see the first and the fourth "no_export" are the same execpt the "dest". I would like them to be the same child and this dest have two leaves: NTT and CNN

Anyone can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Antlr is a tool primarily to lex/parse some input (syntactically), not to interpret the semantics. The resulting parse tree reflects the structure of your input data syntactically, not its semantic meaning. You are trying to gather pieces of information from different places in your input, however, to interpret them semantically.

Instead, simply use a second step when you have the tree above. Antlr will generate visitors or listeners for you if desired ([use the `-visitor` or `-listener` command line options](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/tool-options.md)), with which you can easily traverse the tree to extract and collect your desired data in any data structure you convenient for you.